# nesting array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to simplify nested array of object to array of string without altering original array, but value of countries array of object get changed. How I will rectify so I'll get new array of object in newCountries and old value of array of object not get modified. i/e countries

```js
const countries = {
  "country": [{
      "name": "India",
      "cities": [{
          "name": "Mumbai",
        },
        {
          "name": "Delhi",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Australia",
      "cities": [{
          "name": "Sydney",
        },
        {
          "name": "Melbourne",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

// I have tried following code
var newCountries = Object.assign({}, countries);
newCountries.country.map(val => {
  if (val.cities) {
    var city = val.cities.map(city => {
      return city.name
    });
    val.cities = [];
    val.cities = city;
  }
  return val;
})

console.log('new object\n', newCountries)
console.log('old object\n', countries)
```

```html
<b>output</b>
<pre>
{
  "country": [
   {
     "name": "India",
     "cities": [
       "Mumbai",
       "Delhi"
     ]
   },
   { 
     "name": "Australia",
     "cities": [
       "Sydney",
       "Melbourne"
     ]
   }
 ]
}
</pre>
```

Comment: Make that `val.cities = [...val.cities || [], city]` and you're good.

Comment: @Nishat I've included your attempt on your code, please, next time do it by yourself, always add your attempt and don't add code on coments, use the [edit].

Comment: @CalvinNunes thankyou for suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is a trivial task. Just loop over each country and assign a new array of city names to the existing one by mapping the object to just the value of the "name" key.

You could also try this, assuming `name` is the only key in the object.

```js
country.cities = country.cities.reduce((arr, city) => arr.concat(Object.values(city)), [])
```

You can even simplify this further by using [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
country.cities = country.cities.flatMap(city => Object.values(city))
```

**Note:** `flatMap` is somewhat of an experimental feature in modern browsers.

- Chrome – Version 69 (2018-09-04)
- Edge – **No**
- Firefox – Version 62 (2019-09-03)
- Internet Explorer – **No**
- Opera – Version 56 (2018-09-25 → Chromium 69)
- Safari – Version 12 (2018-09-17)

```js
const countries = {
  "country": [{
    "name": "India",
    "cities": [{
      "name": "Mumbai",
    }, {
      "name": "Delhi",
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Australia",
    "cities": [{
      "name": "Sydney",
    }, {
      "name": "Melbourne",
    }]
  }]
}

// Loop over each country
countries.country.forEach(country => {
  // Replace `{ name : "CITY_NAME" }` with just `"CITY_NAME"`
  country.cities = country.cities.map(city => city.name)
})

console.log(countries);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Nice answer, I'll just point that maybe it worths to mention that `flatMap` is a relative new technology and not all browser versions supports it

Comment: @CalvinNunes noted.